# Null Pointer Exception while putting Image In Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am facing with the NullpointerExcetion while putting image in Bitmap. I am getting Image from SD card.

```
        Uri path = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(path));
    if(imageFile.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }
```

Comment: Since your code does not check for nulls, could you tell us where the NullPointerException occures?

Comment: @shkschneider...last line. myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

Comment: Always post full stacktrace, thanks.

Comment: Test for myImage being null or myBitmap being null, could be many things at this point. Post more infos (stacktrace +1)

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess: `myImage` is `null`. Check that you're importing the correct `R`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an Activity, check if `imageView1` is in the layout you passed to `setContentView` method.

If you are using a fragment or have inflated programmatically a layout, then use `view.findViewBy(R.id.imageView1)` instead